# C++ iterator and reverse iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm writing an `iterator` (actually it is `const_iterator` for my current object, and I want also to create a `reverse_const_iterator` also.

I looked around, to see how to do this and I stumbled across [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/reverse_iterator/):

> Notice however that when an iterator is reversed, the reversed version
>   does not point to the same element in the range, but to the one
>   preceding it. This is so, in order to arrange for the past-the-end
>   element of a range: An iterator pointing to a past-the-end element in
>   a range, when reversed, is changed to point to the last element (not
>   past it) of the range (this would be the first element of the range if
>   reversed). And if an iterator to the first element in a range is
>   reversed, the reversed iterator points to the element before the first
>   element (this would be the past-the-end element of the range if
>   reversed).

Is this what happens from the users' perspective, or when you dereference a `reverse_iterator` does it not abstract this away by giving you the value/reference of the object you *think* it is pointing to? Is this just implementation detail?

My understanding was:

```
for(i = obj.rbegin(); i != obj.rend(); i++)
```

was equivalent to

```
for(i = obj.begin(); i != obj.end(); i++)
```

except in reverse. And so `*i` would go backward through the container in the first case, and go forward through the container in the second case. Is my instinct correct?

Comment: As a side note: When working with iterators you should always use pre-increment (`++i`) instead of post-increment since it can be more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right that it's an abstraction. The reverse iterator contains a normal iterator that points at the element after the object you would get if you dereferenced it. However, it's not merely an implementation detail. The `std::reverse_iterator` adapter provides a member function call `base` which returns the underlying iterator.

The standard defines `std::reverse_iterator` as an iterator adapter with the following relation to the iterator its adapting:

> The fundamental relation between a reverse iterator and its corresponding iterator i is established by the identity: `&*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1)`

A common use for `base` is erasing an element from a container, which would be done like so:

```
it++;
lst.erase(it.base());
```

If you want to do this while iterating over the container in reverse, you would do:

```
it++;
std::list<int>::reverse_iterator(lst.erase(it.base()));
```

Comment: As a side question, why would it ever be useful to get the `base` underlying `iterator`?

Comment: @Bingo: because containers may expect it, for example, `erase` is specified as taking an `iterator` and *not* a `reverse_iterator`.

Comment: @Bingo: yeah... except that as mentioned you need to apply `--` on the base iterator before passing it to the container, and forgetting to do so means that it's not erasing the right element. Painful experience.

Comment: Another side question... eep sorry... if I pass an `iterator` to the constructor of a `reverse_iterator` does that automatically convert it to a `reverse_iterator` too?

Comment: @Bingo It just wrap the `iterator` in the `reverse_iterator`. Your `reverse_iterator` will "point at" the element before the one that the `iterator` points at.

Comment: @sftrabbit also dereference the iterator before erasing, like Matthieu said?

Comment: @Bingo Sorry. The `it++` I just added has the same effect as doing `--` on the result of `base`.

Comment: the very last line of ur code. It constructs a reverse iterator but it didn't get assigned to anything. I think it should be assigned back to `it`, right? Otherwise, the `it.base()` is erased already and keep that around inside `it`, without updating, will cause undefined behavior, right?