# Implementing custom const_reverse_iterator given my custom const_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

Given my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109185/c-iterator-and-reverse-iterator) on iterators and reverse iterators, I now have a working `const_iterator` implementation for my custom class... I want to now create a `const_reverse_iterator` which iterates over the same container.

I implemented my `const_iterator` like

```
class const_iterator : public std::iterator<T, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>
{
    ...
    // operator overloads *, ++, --, ==, !=, e.g.
    uint32_t operator*() const;
    ...
};
```

and I have a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
```

Now, my `crbegin()` and `crend()` implementations look something like this (**the bit I don't think is correct**):

```
const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const
{
    return const_reverse_iterator(this->cend());
}

const_reverse_iterator crend() const
{
    return const_reverse_iterator(this->cbegin());
}
```

The problem:
In my test, the following works fine:

```
for(const_iterator i = line.cbegin(); i != line.cend(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << static_cast<char>(*i); // Display as a 'char' for testing purposes
}
```

But with the following code:

```
for(const_reverse_iterator i = line.crbegin(); i != line.crend(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << static_cast<char>(*i); // Why won't you display as a 'char' from 'unint32_t' like 'const_iterator' does??
}
```

I get the following error on the `std::cout` line:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type 'std::bidirectional_iterator_tag' to type 'char'|
```

Is this a valid way to create hassle-free `reverse_iterators`?

I feel like there is something simple that I am missing, but I searched far and wide, I couldn't quite find an example which showed how to call the constructor on a `std::reverse_iterator<ITERATOR_TYPE>` templated class.

Thanks in advance for your kind words and advice.

### EDIT:

FYI, the solution below, I had to change:

```
class const_iterator : public std::iterator<T, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>
```

to

```
class const_iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, const T>
```

for it to work. Notice also the `const` because I have `const_iterator`s that I'm dealing with.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specialized `iterator` incorrectly, reversing the value type and iterator category.  It should be:

```
class const_iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T>
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As a result, although `const_iterator` works OK when using it directly, anything that depends on its traits e.g. using `<algorithm>`, or `std::reverse_iterator`, will fail.